# Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>`

Tags: spring, kotlin, hibernate, jpa

Добавляю тут вот такую штуку

```kotlin
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "guild_options",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "option_id", referencedColumnName = "id")])
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "option_name")
    @Column(name = "option_value")
    lateinit var options: MutableMap<String, String>
```

Выходит ошибка:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>`
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.UnknownBasicJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(UnknownBasicJavaType.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.InferredBasicValueResolver.from(InferredBasicValueResolver.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:480) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1831) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1682) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1660) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1830) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1816) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: note this is coming with the hibernate 6.2.x i cant find a way to return to 6.1.7.Final. And it would be great if you asked in the english stack overflow, i had to translate.